# Looking for the right RE

Tags: python, regex

Just started with regular expressions...  Im looking  for a regular expression
something like \b\d\d\b but the digits
may not be the same.(e.g 23 should match
but 22 should not) I,ve tried a lot
( involving backreferences ) but they all
failed.
I've tried RE's with the code below
( python 2.7.3) but nothing matched so far

```
import re
# accept a raw string(e) as input
# and return a function with an argument
# 'string' which returns a re.Match object
# on succes. Else it returns None
def myMatch(e):
    RegexObj= re.compile(e)
    return RegexObj.match

menu= raw_input
expr= "expression\n:>"
Quit= 'q'
NewExpression= 'r'
str2match= "string to match\n:>"
validate= myMatch(menu(expr))
# exits when the user # hits 'q'
while True:                     
    # set the string to match or hit 'q' or 'r'
    option = menu(str2match)
    if option== Quit: break 
    #invokes when the user hits 'r'
    #setting the new expression
    elif option== NewExpression:
        validate= myMatch(menu(expr))
        continue
    reMatchObject= validate(option) 
    # we have a match ! 
    if reMatchObject:           
        print "Pattern: ",reMatchObject.re.pattern
        print "group(0): ",reMatchObject.group()
        print "groups: ",reMatchObject.groups()
    else:
        print "No match found "
```

Comment: you can return functions instead of using `lambda` e.g., `return regexobj.match`

Comment: `g = lambda x: f(x)` is redundant redundant in this case. You could use `g = f` instead.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian - I had to read that three times before I got it. Nice. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use backreferencing and a negative lookahead.

```
\b(\d)(?!\1)\d\b
```

The backreference is replaced with whatever was matched in the first group: `(\d)`

A negative lookahead prevents the match from succeeding if the following characters match the expression.

So this basically says match a number (we'll call it "N"). If the next character is N, fail the match. If not, match one more number.